# Nested subchart of Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Can I make nested chart of Helm?

Subchart is defined in Helm Chart spec. e.g. Wordpress chart includes Nginx and MySQL subchart.

Can I define more deep nested chart? e.g. Wordpress chart includes HTTPd chart and the chart also includes Nginx, HAProxy and memcached subchart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, each chart can depend on charts them selves to create a tree like structure of dependencies.

`PrimaryApplication
|- Service1
   |- httpd
   |- Database
|- Service2
   |- haproxy
      |- common`

Comment: Thank you for kind answer. Is there any limit of nest depth? unlimited?

Comment: I don't know and am not familiar enough with the code to even check.